# What is meaing of "A struct cannot have an initializer in the form: base (argument-list)."

Tags: c#

Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Struct constructors are similar to class constructors, except for the following differences:

1. Structs cannot contain explicit
   parameterless constructors. Struct
   members are automatically
   initialized to their default values.
2. A struct cannot have an initializer
       in the form: base (argument-list).

I have problems to understand Item 2. Can someone give me a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, structs do not support inheritance. Although techincally they do inherit from the base class object, item 2 states that you cannot call the base class constructor explicitly.
More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: True. But the MSDN has chosen a very roundabout way of saying this. I’m not sure why they felt this inclusion was relevant at all.

Comment: That page you link to is garbage since it says "When you call the `new` operator on a class, it will be allocated on the heap. However, when you instantiate a struct, it gets created on the stack."

Comment: @Jason - Why is that statement garbage? isn't that true?

Comment: A struct property or field of a class type will not be allocated on the stack, it'll be on the heap with its enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` (implicitly) derive immediately from `System.ValueType` and the only constructor on that `abstract` class is `protected` and parameterless. These are facts by the language specification and the statement you are questioning is a consequence of these facts and stated explicitly in the language specification from §11.3.8:

> A `struct` instance constructor is not permitted to include a constructor initializer of the form `base(...)`.

For reference types that derive from classes that have an accessible non-parameterless constructor, you can do the following:

```
class Base {
    private readonly string baseName;
    public string BaseName { get { return this.baseName; } }
    public Base(string baseName) { this.baseName = baseName; }
}

class Derived : Base {
    private readonly string derivedName;
    public string DerivedName { get { return this.derivedName; } }

    public Derived(string baseName, string derivedName) : base(baseName) {
        this.derivedName = derivedName;
    }
}
```

The point is that a `Derived` is a `Base` and as such, a constructor for `Base` needs to be invoked to completely initialize the new instance of `Derived` (i.e., the parts of `Derived` that make it a `Base` need to be initialized). Invoking the base constructor through the syntax `base(...)` lets you invoke the appropriate constructor.

The statement you are questioning about `struct` states that it is not permitted to have such an invocation. This is mostly because there can never be such a constructor per the facts stated in the first sentence of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an initializer in the form: base (argument-list).

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int i) { Debug.WriteLine(i); }
}

public class Bar: Foo
{
    public Bar() : base(4) {} // Prints '4' to debug via the base class's constructor.
}
```

Structs do not support inheritance, so explicitly calling the base class's constructor is not allowed.